# PHP code doesnt "compile" when connecting via sockets

Tags: php, sockets, http, http-headers, mirc

I am writing a script for mIRC that will fetch data from my webserver, that code is generated via PHP.

It works just fine when i connect via my browser (firefox).
However, when i connect via the mIRC sockets, server fails to "compile" my PHP code. I can still able to fetch any other text or html. Seems like the webserver (litespeed) does not acknowledge my http requests(?!)

This is my header information that I pass to the server:

```
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg GET /ccsw/ccsw.php?action=register&username= $+ %ccsw_username_temp $+ &password= $+ %ccsw_username_temp HTTP/1.1
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Host: www.[HIDDEN].com
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Connection: close
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Accept-Encoding: gzip
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Accept:Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
  ;sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Cache-Control: no-cache
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg Pragma: no-cache
  sockwrite -n ccsw_sock_reg $crlf
```

I've tried using a apache server instead of litespeed, but it doesn't solve either. I still don't get any PHP generated code to show.

Am i missing some headers? Should I do it in a completely different way?

**update:**

mIRC code:

```
alias testsock {
  sockclose testsock
  sockopen testsock www.[HIDDEN].com 80
}
on *:sockopen:testsock: {
  sockwrite -nt testsock GET /ccsw/ccsw.php?action=register&username= $+ %ccsw_username_temp $+ &password= $+ %ccsw_username_temp HTTP/1.0
  sockwrite -nt testsock Host: www.[HIDDEN].com
  sockwrite -nt testsock $crlf  
} 

on *:sockread:testsock: {
  %ccsw_content_start = 0

  if ($sockerr > 0) return
  sockread %temp
  while ($sockbr) {
    echo response: %temp
    sockread %temp
  }
}
```

response:

```
reponse: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
reponse: Date: Thu, 02 May 2013 14:45:07 GMT
reponse: Server: LiteSpeed
reponse: Connection: close
reponse: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
reponse: Content-Type: text/html
reponse: Content-Length: 43
reponse:
```

and after that last "reponse: " i should get a php generated line with "reponse: true"
the "reponse: " is just a prefix for my echo..

Comment: what response do you get when requesting a php file? An error? A disconnect? The php source? And have you checked your logs (both Apache AND PHP logs)?

Comment: Have you noticed that on the 6th line you have `Accept:Accept:` twice?

Comment: First stop should always be both access- and error logs for the webserver. Especially Apache logs *everything* that might be relevant, in the first on success, in the second on failure.

Comment: (im new to stackopverflow, dunno if i can reply to a specific comment?)

when i request a php file i get all content of it except anything between <?php ?> tags.. so basically just the HTTP Headers and the html/text.

i havnt noticed the dual Accept:! ill give it a try!

unfortunately i dont have access to the server logs (webhosting service) last resort could of course be to setup a local apache just for testing..

Thanks alot, ill give all your suggestions ago and come back :)

Comment: "when i request a php file i get all content of it except anything between <?php ?> tags" ... um... that's how it is supposed to work. everything between php tags is something that is supposed to be processed by the server, not sent to the client.

Comment: and you should have local apache for testing. it should be no "last resort", but first step *before* you deploy your code in the hosting environment. I don't know how you've managed to develop anything without logs and without local deployment.

Comment: i removed the second Accept: but it didnt do it.
I had access to the log-files! ive checked them, but i cant find anything unusual. looks like normal HTTP GET requests and nothing in the error.log

Comment: eis, ok i mean i dont get any php generated content.. all text/html content gets loaded..

well its easier for me to just go with my webhosting :P

Comment: check the first post for my mIRC script and response..

The php script should return true if its provided with a username and a password.. and when i echo that row of sockwrite it looks OK. (ie the variables works.)

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully you will see the following response header
"Content-Length: 43"
That means you are getting response and the problem lies inside your SOCKREAD event.

**Try this following code:**

```
on *:sockread:testsock: {
  if ($sockerr) {
    return
  }

  var %line
  :start
  sockread %line
  if (%line) {
    echo -ag SOCKREAD: %line
  }
  if ($sockbr) {
    goto start
  }
}
```